# In IPhone how do we know the country or city code of the user

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

Say I am in Jakarta.

My country is 62 and my city is 21.

If a phone is 123456789 it really is 62 21 123456789

So I need to prepend 62 and 21 to 1234567689 before calling the call function.

How do I do so in objective-c

Comment: I don't understand- your title asks how to determine the country or city code, but you are asking how to make a call with a specific set of codes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you looked into `[NSLocale currentLocale];`?